# React Native Error on AsyncStorage even if I used the one from '@react-native-community/async-storage'

Tags: react-native

I am still having this errpr  `ERROR    Warning: AsyncStorage has been extracted from react-native core and will be removed in a future release. It can now be installed and imported from '@react-native-community/async-storage' instead of 'react-native'. See https://github.com/react-native-community/async-storage` even if i have installed and imported the new `AsyncStorage` mentioned.

here is what my App.js looks like

```
// @refresh reset

import React, {useState, useEffect, useCallback} from 'react';
import {StyleSheet, TextInput, View, Button} from 'react-native';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage';

...
```

package.json

```
...
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/async-storage": "^1.12.0",
...
```

Comment: Are you sure you haven't used AsyncStorage from 'react-native' anywhere ? Also make sure to check that installed other third library are using AsyncStorage from react native or not.

Comment: So far i only have App.js. no other components made. I also made sure i linked it according to the documentation (i followed the steps and confirmed the files gradle files under android). other libraries i am using is just `firebase` and `react-native-gifted-chat`

Answer (score 0):

I lost track on the issue but I believe that at the time where I experienced this error, I had a certain version of Expo SDK that triggered it. **Upgrading to 39 or higher will surely fix this issue** .